# Trying to run docker image of hortonworks giving 0.0.0.0:2181 failed to port is already allocated

Tags: docker, hortonworks-sandbox

I am following hortonworks dockerization document from hortonworks and running below commands after downloading "HDP_2.6.5_deploy-scripts_180624d542a25.zip" file.

After extracts , I executed "docker-deploy-hdp265.sh" file.

It executes two commands 
docker start sandbox-hdp
docker start sandbox-proxy

first one run perfectly and when I execute "docker start sandbox-proxy" it gives below error

```html
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint sandbox-proxy (7d3f4a490fc3d782c36ba4bf35921a896acc3edf35d2bf4d9522aebfeea002f5): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:2181 failed: port is already allocated
Error: failed to start containers: sandbox-proxy
```

please suggest what I am doing wrong, 
I also, use this command to update host files

```html
sudo echo '127.0.0.1 sandbox.hortonworks.com sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com sandbox-hdf.hortonworks.com' | sudo tee -a
127.0.0.1 sandbox.hortonworks.com sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com sandbox-hdf.hortonworks.c
```

Comment: Without knowing too much, I'd say that you probably have the port allocated, ie. used by another service. Try to figure out what ports are in use, maybe change the port used by the container, or stop the one running.

Answer (score -1):

use below command:

sudo lsof -nP | grep LISTEN|grep 2181

check if anything is running on this port

kill that process